# How do you handle 100s of permissions in ABP

Tags: permissions, claims, abp

It seems policies / permissions are directly checked against claims.  How can ABP be used in an enterprise application that has hundreds of permissions?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems policies / permissions are directly checked against claims.

That is not true. Permissions are indirectly checked against these claims:

- `AbpClaimTypes.UserId` by `UserPermissionValueProvider`
- `AbpClaimTypes.Role` (role names) by `RolePermissionValueProvider`
- `AbpClaimTypes.ClientId` by `ClientPermissionValueProvider`

For each claim, permissions are checked against `PermissionGrant` in the cache or database.

More about Permission Value Providers:
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.3/Authorization#permission-value-providers

> How can ABP be used in an enterprise application that has hundreds of permissions?

In most cases, grant multiple permissions to a role and then grant a role to multiple users.
(You can also grant permissions directly to user, since the permissions are not stored in claims.)

There is ongoing development to not use claims for roles, then hundreds of roles will be no issue:
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/8620